# Make a system of linear equations determined

Tags: linear-algebra

I am solving a system of linear equations $Ax= y$ in $n$ dimensions and I have found that in my case a matrix $A$ is upper diagonal with zeros on the main diagonal, while the next diagonal has non-zero values. So, iirc from my LA courses, it means that $\mathrm{rank}(A) = n-1$ and if I provide a proper extra condition, it will make this system determined.

In my case $x$ is a vector of values a certain function takes at predefined points and $A$ corresponds to the numerical integration scheme, more precisely a trapezoid rule. I hence thought that I may have a freedom in assigning boundary values to $x$, say making $x_n = 0$. However in such case it would constitute to replacing the lower row of the matrix form of $A$ with the $e_n$ basis vector, i.e. $a_{nj} = 0$ for $j < n$ as before but now $a_{nn} = 1$. However, since $a_{00}$ is still $0$, the rank of $A$ is still $n-1$. What am I missing here and how should I properly reguarize $A$?

Comment: If $a_{00}=0$, the matrix is still full rank. $\text{rank}(A)=\text{colrank}(A)$, and you have columns $$(0,0,\dots,1),(a_{12},0,0,\dots,1),(a_{13},a_{23},0,0,\dots,1),\dots,(a_{1n},a_{2n},\dots,a_{n-1,n},1)$$ which form a basis of $\mathbb{R}^n$ if none of the $a_{i,j}$'s are $0$. [See this 3x3 example on WolframAlpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=rank%28%7B%7B0%2Ca%2Cb%7D%2C%7B0%2C0%2Cc%7D%2C%7B1%2C1%2C1%7D%7D%29).

Comment: @DanielP in the original matrix the first column and the last row are zero. In the resulting the first column still stays zero, correct?

Comment: I guess I misunderstood your question then. If you have a $0$-column, then the rank can at most be $n-1$.